# It is possible to get a list of post types asociated to a taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I use More Plugin (More Types, More Fields and More Taxonomy) to create custom taxonomies, post types and fields.

I've created a select control filled with taxonomies (looping through `$wp_taxonomies`).

What I need is to show a list of post types associated with currently selected taxonomies (I will do this by using jQuery) and I didn't figure out how to get such a list of post types. Thanks!

Comment: `$wp_taxonomies['YOURTAXNAME']->object_type` holds an array of post types that use the given taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

You retrieve it with `$wp_taxonomies` already. I just wrote it down, so you'll probably have to try a little to get the following lines of code up and running, but it should give you an idea of how it should work (see it as reference/pseudo code):

EDIT: After a note from [Mike Schinkel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/89/mikeschinkel) i updated the code to make it easier to ignore built in taxonomies (see: _builtin). I hope Mike will post the example he sent me here, so his (much easier) sollution can be marked as the final approach...

```
// equals the following $keys
$wp_taxonomies['category'] == $wp_taxonomies[0];
$wp_taxonomies['post_tag'] == $wp_taxonomies[1];
$wp_taxonomies['nav_menu'] == $wp_taxonomies[2];
$wp_taxonomies['link_category'] == $wp_taxonomies[3];

// after $key #3 you retrieve all different registered taxonomies
$all_tax = count($wp_taxonomies)-4; // gives you the amount of reg. tax.

// Here starts the actual code
$post_types = array(); // some empty array to save your post types for further procesing
$i = 0;
foreach ( $wp_taxonomies as $tax ) {
if ( !$tax->_builtin)
  $post_type_arr = $tax[$i]->object_type; // array of post types in the current taxonomy
  foreach ( $post_type_arr as $arr ) : // loop through all post types assigned to the taxonomy
    $post_types[] .= $arr; // assign them to our array of post types
  endforeach;
  $i++;
}
$post_types = array_unique($post_types); // drop doublettes out of the array
var_dump($post_types);

# expected result close to this...

# Array(
#   1 => $post_type_a,
#   2 => $post_type_b,
#   3 => $post_type_n
# );
```

Comment: Slight syntax error in your code mate, `enforeach;` should be `endforeach;`.. ;)

Comment: Thanks kaiser! With some minor changes your code was I looking for...

Comment: @Valentin & t31os: n/p. Could you please edit my code, so other people may reuse it? 
@Valentin: Please mark it as the sollution (Check on left side below voting). Thanks.

Comment: See my edit above: Please *do not* mark it as the sollution.

Answer (score 1):

So this is the *real* solution:

```
function get_object_types_unique( $all_r_custom = false ) {
    $tax_object = get_taxonomies( array( '_builtin' => $all_r_custom ), 'objects' );
    if ( $all_r_custom == true )
        $tax_object = array_merge( $tax_object, get_taxonomies( array( '_builtin' => false ), 'objects' ) );

    $object_types = array();
    foreach ( $tax_object as $tax ) {
        $object_types = array_merge( $object_types, $tax->object_type );
    }

    $object_types = array_unique( $object_types );
    return $object_types;
}
```

It allows to either retrieve only custom post/object types with `get_object_types_unique()` or all incl. built in object types `get_object_types_unique( true )`. So far there's with this function no chance to retrieve only the built in object types, because i can't see a need so far.